# Octave input from keyboard not working in a script

Tags: octave

I'm writing a script in octave that needs an input from keyboard in order to select a function to be used further. I've read the documentation and understood that

```
ans = input("choose...")
```

should wait for the for the input and store it in the ans variable. When I use it in the octave terminal it works just fine, but it doesn't when I insert it in my script : It shows the message "choose..." but it doesn't wait.

I don't get it, What I am missing.

Thanks,

Comment: It should work. What version of the interpreter you're using? We're at [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/)

Comment: Actually I had an archaic 3.2 version. Upgraded to 3.8 and it works fine. Thanks for pointing it out